# Storing Vertexes on a Geometric Dome

Tags: algorithm, geometry, storage

So, I'm kinda lost. For the game I'm working on, I want to make the 'world' a geometric dome (sphere made of equilateral triangles). In order to generate the world and play the world, I need to find a way to save all the edges and vertexes and be able to calculate neighbors. I'm unsure how to save all of the different vertexes and edges in a way that you could easily figure out which points neighbor each edge and which edges neighbor each point. What methods could I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you ask.  [Wavefront OBJ files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) store the coordinates of each vertex as an indexed list, and then define each face as and cycle of vertex indices clockwise around the face normal.

I don't like this because you have to do processing to figure out certain aspects of connectivity.  For a triangle mesh as you are describing, I prefer to store the vertices, and their 1-ring.  The 1-ring are the indices of the adjacent vertices clockwise around the vertex.

Doing it this way allows you to move from triangle to triangle much easier.  If for vertex V you have it's 1 ring (v1, v2, v3, v4), then you immediately know it's on triangles (v, v1, v2), (v, v2, v3), ..., (v, v4, v1). for example.

This blog post goes into more detail: http://bluntobject.wordpress.com/2007/03/13/mesh-data-structures-vol-2-vertex-one-rings/

If a vertex is on the boundary or is non-manifold, you don't have a complete 1-ring.  I handle this as a list of partial 1-chains.

Comment: The 1-ring approach sounds great! How would i generate the mesh/sphere and all the triangles originally?

Comment: @TheNickmaster21, that's quite a different question!  If one single tessellation of the sphere is good enough and you can reuse it, just download a .OBJ and read the data in.  It's pretty easy.  If you need to be more adaptive then it's too much to answer here.  A Google search for "sphere tessellation" gives a lot of hits though.  My approach would be start with an inscribed tetrahedron and subdivide to the resolution you want.

Comment: @TheNickmaster21, Expanding on my previous comment, you can put a single vertex at the apex, and several vertices around the base.  Perhaps 5 or 6 to get the aspect ratio of the triangles that suites you best.  Then each triangular face can be subdivided into 4 faces by dividing the edges and projecting onto the sphere.

Comment: I think I could easily just save a few spheres of different sizes to use depending on the size of the current world/planet. If I save all the vertexes and use the 1-ring concept for the neighbors, how should I store the edges? I'd love to the just call them using the number/key/value of the two vertexes around it but I'm not sure how that could be done. Would there be an easy way to do that?

Comment: No need to store the edges, you know the triangles from the 1-ring, and the edges as well.  You can also interpret the 1-ring as a list of the edges incident to a vertex.

Comment: I need to store data in the edges though. Each edge is like a significant chunk of the world :P How would I do that?

Comment: I suppose you could store that in the 1-ring.  If v[j] is in the 1-ring of v[i], then e[i,j] is a half edge, as is e[j,i].  A shared pointer in the j position of the i 1-ring an the i position of the j 1-ring should do the trick.  Note that this also allows you to associate data with a half edge (oriented edge) as well.

Comment: Sounds like that will work nicely! I just need to make sure i can share the pointers properly and such.